# How to calculate the sum of all columns of a 2D numpy array (efficiently)

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have the following 2D numpy array consisting of four rows and three columns:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
>>> print(a)
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]
```

What would be an efficient way to generate a 1D array that contains the sum of all columns (like `[18, 22, 26]`)? Can this be done without having the need to loop through all columns?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [`numpy.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), paying particular attention to the `axis` parameter. To sum over columns:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
>>> a.sum(axis=0)
array([18, 22, 26])
```

Or, to sum over rows:

```
>>> a.sum(axis=1)
array([ 3, 12, 21, 30])
```

Other aggregate functions, like [`numpy.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html), [`numpy.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and [`numpy.std`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html), e.g., also take the `axis` parameter.

From the [Tentative Numpy Tutorial](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#Basic_Operations):

> Many unary operations, such as computing the sum of all the elements
>   in the array, are implemented as methods of the `ndarray` class.  By
>   default, these operations apply to the array as though it were a list
>   of numbers, regardless of its shape. However, by specifying the `axis`
>   parameter you can apply an operation along the specified axis of an
>   array:

Comment: OK, thanks. So this is a somewhat function dependent solution. Is there also a more generic approach?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.  Summing over an axis or axes of a numpy array is done with the `sum` function.  Is that a problem?  Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: This is a good answer.  I generally prefer `a.sum(axis=0)` to `a.sum(0)` however.  (I think it's slightly more explicit -- which is never a bad thing)

Comment: @mgilson, you're right, especially in this context.  I'll edit my answer to use the named argument explicitly.

Comment: @Puggie, perhaps by “more generic” you mean “not using built-in NumPy functions”? In general, you are far better off using the functions built into NumPy, for several reasons: they have been optimized by the NumPy development team, there's less code for you to maintain, and your code will be far more readable. The `np.sum` function is in a sense the most generic *and* the most efficient, since it hides the implementation and presumably takes advantage of the numpy dev's knowledge of numpy internals. Functions are good—use them.

Comment: @Will, I agree with you using the built-in, optimized functions. By "more generic approach" I meant: is there a generic approach to perform any column specific operation or function? These days I use `pandas`, which allows for this by its `apply` function.

Comment: @Puggie, ah, now I see what you mean, though the question does ask for the sum. In that case, see [`np.apply_along_axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html#numpy-apply-along-axis) and [`np.apply_over_axes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html#numpy-apply-over-axes).

Comment: @JohnVinyard Could I suggest you add Will's `apply_along_axis` or `apply_over_axes` comment as a final bit to your answer?

Comment: Bear in mind that  `np.apply_along_axis` will be orders of magnitude slower than supplying the `axis=` to `np.sum` etc., since the latter takes advantage of vectorization to avoid looping in Python.

Comment: @JohnVinyard - What if I wanted to sum only a subset of the columns (or rows)? Is there a way to specify a set of indices to sum along a certain axis? Thanks!

Comment: I have an ndarray of shape (15, 9) and when I ndarray.mean(axis=0), it does it as expected but the shape is (9,). I need a mean array of shape (1,9). What should I do?

Answer (score 12):

Other alternatives for summing the columns are

```py
numpy.einsum('ij->j', a)
```

and

```py
numpy.dot(a.T, numpy.ones(a.shape[0]))
```

If the number of rows and columns is in the same order of magnitude, all of the possibilities are roughly equally fast:

[image]

If there are only a few columns, however, both the `einsum` and the `dot` solution significantly outperform numpy's `sum` (note the log-scale):

[image]

---

Code to reproduce the plots:

```py
import numpy
import perfplot


def numpy_sum(a):
    return numpy.sum(a, axis=1)


def einsum(a):
    return numpy.einsum('ij->i', a)


def dot_ones(a):
    return numpy.dot(a, numpy.ones(a.shape[1]))


perfplot.save(
    "out1.png",
    # setup=lambda n: numpy.random.rand(n, n),
    setup=lambda n: numpy.random.rand(n, 3),
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(15)],
    kernels=[numpy_sum, einsum, dot_ones],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='len(a)',
    )
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `axis` argument:

```
>> numpy.sum(a, axis=0)
  array([18, 22, 26])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`numpy.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html). for your case, it is

```
sum = a.sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Then NumPy `sum` function takes an optional axis argument that specifies along which axis you would like the sum performed:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
>>> a.sum(0)
array([18, 22, 26])
```

Or, equivalently:

```
>>> numpy.sum(a, 0)
array([18, 22, 26])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.sum(0)
```

should solve the problem. It is a 2d `np.array` and you will get the sum of all column. `axis=0` is the dimension that points downwards and `axis=1` the one that points to the right.