# How to populate an empty array selectively?

Tags: arrays, numpy, populate

I am new to python and have tried to accomplish the following with only little success:

In a folder there are *.columns files that do all contain 5 (0-4) columns and 500 rows. I need to sum up the columns 1-4 over all *.columns files and plot the result against the first column of any of that (all equal).

I created an empty array in which I want to paste the first (0) column of array "x_array3" and the columns 1-4 from "y_array0". All of them have the same size (500L, 5L).

Could You please give me an advice how to proceed? I am lost right now.

Christian

```
import glob
import numpy as np


ListOfFiles = glob.glob("*.columns")
y_array0 = 0

for filename in ListOfFiles:
    y_array1 = np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header = 1, usecols = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
    y_array0 = y_array0 + y_array1

x_array3 = np.genfromtxt(ListOfFiles[0], skip_header = 1, usecols = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4))

empty_array = np.empty(shape=(500, 5))

ausgabe_array = ??? here I'm stuck ???

np.savetxt('SX_DOS.out', ausgabe_array)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need an emtpy array. I guess you probably need to sum up columns 1 to 4 inside the loop: `accum += data[:,1:]` and then plot that directly after the loop: `plt.plot(data[:,0], accum)`

Answer (score 1):

I have found a working solution. I read in all the columns as single arrays and merge them at the end. Still, can anybody give me a hint how one populates an empty array with selected items from another array (with another size)?

Chr.

```
import glob
import numpy as np

ListOfFiles = glob.glob("*.columns")
y_array_s0 = 0
y_array_p0 = 0
y_array_d0 = 0
y_array_f0 = 0

for filename in ListOfFiles:
    y_array_s1 = np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header = 1, usecols = (1))
    y_array_s0 = y_array_s0 + y_array_s1

    y_array_p1 = np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header = 1, usecols = (2))
    y_array_p0 = y_array_p0 + y_array_p1

    y_array_d1 = np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header = 1, usecols = (3))
    y_array_d0 = y_array_d0 + y_array_d1

    y_array_f1 = np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header = 1, usecols = (4))
    y_array_f0 = y_array_f0 + y_array_f1

x_array3 = np.genfromtxt(ListOfFiles[0], skip_header = 1, usecols = (0))

ausgabe_array = np.transpose(np.array((x_array3, y_array_s0, y_array_p0, y_array_d0,y_array_f0)))

np.savetxt('SX_DOS.out', ausgabe_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to sum columns in an imported array.

Assuming this is working:

```
y_array1 = np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header = 1, usecols = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

then

```
y_array0 = y_array1.sum(axis=0)
```

should give the [sum of the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13567388/1461850).

With regard to plotting, I would recommend [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! I think i described my problem in a wrong way. I do not need a summation of a column in one file. I need to sum up all the elements on a certain position over all files in that folder and put that sum into an array element on the same position. The loop does this, but also makes the first column useless (as I ask genfromtxt to import it due to the arraysize...).                                                            Christian