# Iteration through a pixel-column

Tags: python, jython, imagej

I am trying to programm a little plugin for ImageJ/Fiji with Jython. Therefore I have to iterate through a pixel-column. Unfortunately the command

```
pixels = ip.getPixels()
```

results in array sorted by pixel-rows. So i wrote something to get the sum of pixel values per column (which fullfill a small query).

```
x = imp.getWidth()
y = imp.getHeight() - 1
pixels = ip.getPixels()
j = 0

for j in range(x):
    print(j)
    i = j
    tempx = x - j
    su = 0
    for i in range((x * y) - 1):

      if pixels[i] > 0:
        su = su + 1
      else:
        su = su + 0  
      i = i + tempx -1

    print(su)
```

But it seems to just get the sum of all pixels of the picture (fullfilling the query). In my opinion there is a problem with the second for loop, but I am too much a beginner to understand why. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: This problem may be answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567345/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-columns-of-a-2d-numpy-array-efficiently

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the problem is probably with the second for loop.

```
for i in range((x * y) - 1):
```

That will run from 0 to the (almost) the number of pixels in the image (width*height-1). 
I think the loop you want is

```
for i in range(y):
    if pixels[i+j*(y+1)] > 0:
```

It's good practise but I'm sure there is a much more pythonic way to do what you want