# Summing arrays fast

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to sum arrays like vectors with

```
import numpy as np

def a_sum(array_list):
    array_sum = array_list[0]
    for i in range(len(array_list) - 1):
        array_sum = np.add(array_sum, array_list[i + 1])
    return array_sum
```

This functions is called many times which so i need to optimize it somehow. Is there a way?

Sample input-output:

```
In []: a_sum([[1,2],[3,4], [5,6]])
Out[]: array([ 9, 12])
```

Comment: `np.sum(array_list)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13567388/2336654 is one of many examples that already show this.  You are trying to sum over rows.

Comment: Yes, you just need to pass `axis=0` to np.sum. `(a_sum(arrs) == np.sum(arrs, axis=0)).all()` returns True.

Comment: @ayhan Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`np.sum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html).

```
import numpy as np

def a_sum(array_list):
    return np.sum(array_list, axis=0)
```

You would see the biggest improvement directly using numpy arrays directly in your code, otherwise numpy will always convert python lists to its datatypes, wasting time.

Comment: Which gives me sum of elements in arrays. Not what I want.

Comment: @UpmostScarab the code you have written sums the elements

Comment: The code you provided does the exact same thing that `np.sum()` does. What do you want?

Comment: @enrico.bacis it give me [a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1], ...  ]

Comment: @UpmostScarab: what are `a` and `b` ? your function only takes one input.

Comment: @enrico.bacis Sorry its a_sum([a,b]) where's a and b are arrays

Comment: Just `np.sum()` both and add them together.

Comment: You should use a numpy array of numpy arrays and then use the `axis` parameter of np.sum to specify the direction of the summation.

Comment: `sum([np.sum(a) for a in list_of_arrays])`

Comment: Also, if your input is actually a Python list, convert it to a NumPy array via `numpy.asarray(my_list)`

Comment: @UpmostScarab check now

Answer (score 0):

Just use `np.sum()`:

```
np.sum(array_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [np.sum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)

```
np.sum(array_list)
```