# Python dataframe: calculating average/diff/sum/... over all columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame (i.e. thousands of rows and 20 columns) and I want to calculate the average (or any other mathmathical function like the total sum etc) over all columns. example:

```
x = [
 [0.5 0.7 0.1 4 80 101],
 [0.1 0.7 0.8 5 4 58],
 [0.4 0.1 0.6 6 1 66],
  ...
 [0.9 0.4 0.1 7 44 12]
]
```

This should result in

```
avg = [0.475 0.95 ...]
```

or

```
sum = [15.1 8.17 ...]
```

Is there any quick formula or oneliner that can easily apply this formula? It does not have to be a pandas.DataFrame, a Numpy array is also good

Comment: This is bound to be answered already. Voting to close, also, did you try calling sum() and mean() on your numpy array? Maybe specifying an axis=x ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the sum of all columns of a 2D numpy array (efficiently)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567345/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-columns-of-a-2d-numpy-array-efficiently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df.mean(axis=0)
df.sum(axis=0)
```